# Postgres query shuffles values in double precision[] when using WHERE condition

Tags: arrays, postgresql, conditional-statements

I have a view that I am querying where the query provides a mix of results depending on the conditions that are included.  The table retrieves the stock symbol, close price (cc), EMA20, and EMA50.  The close, EMA20, and EMA50 are double precision arrays where the value at first index corresponds to the more recent timevalue.

Without any conditions:

- close price array is stored as `[186.17, 185.94, 181.84, 178.94, 176.47]`
- EMA20 array is stored as `{177.781517686655,176.898519548408,175.94678476403,175.326446318138,174.946072246363}`
- EMA50 array is stored as `{173.328052542577,172.803891421866,172.267723724799,171.877018570709,171.588733614412}`

When the following query is used, the values of the arrays are shuffled and provides results that should not be returned if the correct array values were evaluated.

```
SELECT ticker, exchange, cc, EMA20, EMA50
FROM symbolsview
WHERE 
    exchange IN('NYSE', 'NASDAQ', 'AMEX')
    AND (EMA20[1] > EMA50[1])
    AND ((cc[1] <= EMA50[1]) OR (ll[1] <= EMA50[1]))
    AND (cc[2] >= EMA50[2])
```

When I run this query, the values for the same symbols are:

- close:  `{176.47,178.94,186.17,185.94,181.84}`
- EMA20: `{174.946072246363,175.326446318138,177.781517686655,176.898519548408,175.94678476403}`
- EMA50: `{171.588733614412,171.877018570709,173.328052542577,172.803891421866,172.267723724799}`

The values for these columns have been shifted for some reason.  Also when I add another criteria 'AND ticker = 'XXX' where XXX is the ticker value, no results are shown where without this additional criteria showed up in the query results.  If I query the view without any conditions, the arrays are returned with values in the correct order.

There is a table that contains values in a JSON[] column.  The stored view creates the the close, EMA20, and EMA50 double precision from a JSON[].   The view extracts the values and performs an array_agg.  See code below.

```
SELECT ticker, 
        array_agg(obj->>'EMA20')::float[] as EMA20,
        array_agg(obj->>'EMA50')::float[] as EMA50,
        array_agg(obj->>'low')::float[] as ll, 
        array_agg(obj->>'close')::float[] as cc
        FROM symbols, jsonb_array_elements(symbols.last5stats) obj
```

Any insight on why the arrays are being shuffled would be helpful.

Comment: What is the column "ll"?

Comment: Your query doesn't shuffle the data.  If apparently shuffled data gets returned, that is because you have actually stored some data which is the shuffling of other stored data.

Comment: column 'll" is another array which contains the "low" prices.

I have edited the original post to include how the arrays are formed. There is another table which contains a column with JSON[].  The arrat for EMA20, EMA50, close are generated from this json[].  There is a field for each element that contains a timestamp.

Comment: The problem must be in your view definition, so you should share the table definition and sample table data that exhibit the problem.